# How to acquire DJI Onboard SDK control permission without remote control (or turned off remote control)

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm planning to make automatic landing and battery charging system based on DJI M100 and Onboard SDK. It should work for long period (months) autonomously.
The problem is I can't get Onboard SDK control permission without remote controller turned on and mode is switched to "F". 
Is it possible to set up DJI M100 drone to get control from Onboard SDK after power on without remote controller connected?

Answer (score 0):

I tested with N3 with firmware before July 2017. It does allow you to arm or disarms the drone directly through the OSDK (3.2 if i remember correctly). Whether it is a public firmware or DJI supplier only firmware, that I dont know. I didn`t touch on the hardware and gain. Just Implementing software navigation module

I accidentally run the software b4 turning on the lightbridge2. The result is I almost killed myself.